# How to use sockets to read data from server?

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, readline

The app has MainActivity(contains an EditText and a Button) and DisplayActivity(contains a single TextView)The user enters a message in the EditText and presses the send button. The message string from the EditText gets sent to the server. Then starts a new intent to DisplayActivity. DisplayActivity will read data from the server with readLine(), and set TextView from the data received from the server.

activity_main.xml has a EditText with id="@+id/message_textView" and Button with id="@+id/send_button". DisplayActivity has android:id="@+id/displayTextView".

**My code to send data to the server works, but when I try to read data from the server, readline() just stops there and sits there forever.**

Android app has MainActivity and DisplayActivity class.

I run the server code in eclipse.

Server code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyServer {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         int portNumber = 4442;

         System.out.println("Starting server..");

         try {
             while(true) {
             ServerSocket serverSocket =
                 new ServerSocket(portNumber);
             Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
             PrintWriter out =
                 new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
             String message = in.readLine();
             System.out.println(message);//Just print to console, to test if server got message
             out.println(message);
             serverSocket.close();
             clientSocket.close();
//           out.close();
//           in.close();
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                 + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
     }
}
```

MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private EditText messageET;
    private Button sendButton;
    private String message;

    static String hostIP = "10.0.2.2";
    static int port = 4442;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        messageET = findViewById(R.id.message_textView);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = messageET.getText().toString();
                messageET.setText("");

                MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
                myTask.execute();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try
            {
                client = new Socket(hostIP, port);
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                //printWriter.write(message);
                printWriter.println(message);
                //printWriter.flush();
                printWriter.close();
                client.close();
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

DisplayActivity

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;


public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //final String TAG = "displayactivitylog";
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    private TextView displayTV;
    private String msgReceived = null;

    String hostIP = "10.0.2.2";
    int port = 4442;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        displayTV = findViewById(R.id.displayTextView);
        ReadTask readTask = new ReadTask();
        readTask.execute();
    }
    class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = "";
            try
            {
                //create a new socket and attempt to read from it
                socket = new Socket(hostIP,port);
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                //*****the app stops on this line, and nothing happens after*****  
                msgReceived = bufferedReader.readLine();
                //************************************ 
//                while((msgReceived = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
//                    result += msgReceived;
//                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                socket.close();
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
        //update the TextView with the message from the server
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            displayTV.setText(s);
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```

When i run debugger, it literally just stops in DisplayActivity.java on msgReceived = bufferedReader.readLine() in the doInBackground() method and gives no error.

My server starts fine and when I send data from my app to the server, on eclipse it prints out what was sent(and sometimes null for some reason).

[image]

**---------------SOLUTION---------------**

Question was answered by green apps, but basically the server class expects to read something when a connection first opens, and then send out data. However in ReadTask, all it does is try to read data from the server(but it should send data first, then read from it)

Updated code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText messageET;
    private Button sendButton;
    static String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        messageET = findViewById(R.id.message_textView);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = messageET.getText().toString();
                messageET.setText("");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

DisplayActivity.java

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    private TextView displayTV;
    private String msgReceived = null;

    String hostIP = "10.0.2.2";
    int port = 4442;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        displayTV = findViewById(R.id.displayTextView);
        ReadTask readTask = new ReadTask();
        readTask.execute();
    }
    class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = "";
            try
            {
                //create a new socket and attempt to write to it first then read from it
                socket = new Socket(hostIP,port);
                //add data to the server
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                printWriter.println(MainActivity.message);
                //get a stream, to be able to read data from the server
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                msgReceived = bufferedReader.readLine();
                displayTV.setText(msgReceived);
                //close the socket connections
                printWriter.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                socket.close();
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's supposed to stop until data arrives. 'For some reason' is that you've reached end of stream, as stated in the Javadoc, which in the case of a socket means that the peer closed the connection, which means that you must do likewise.

Comment: OP, sorry for posting in this thread since your problem has been solved already, but I couldn't reproduce the "null" message that you have received. @EJP sorry for taking your time as well, could you give an explanation for "null" in the console?

Comment: the only case it appears in the console is, if `message` variable in this line `printWriter.println(message);` is null. it doesn't seem to be related to socket open/close issues

Comment: on the other hand, the message comes from `getText()` method of "EditText", and that method never returns null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two clientsocketss. And two serversockets.

Which is a very strange approach.

The first client sends a line and closes the connection. This works ok as the server tries to read that line and does. Both then close.

Then you start the second client. This one connects to a new serversocket. But this client directly tries to read a line. As the server also tries to read a line from this new client both will wait for eternity on readLine().

Comment: Hey I fixed it after you told me what was wrong. In MainActivity.java i removed the AsyncTask. In DisplayActivity.java I added more code to the ReadTask(to write to the server). Also null does not appear in the server anymore.

Comment: Well done. I would have advised you as such if you only had asked ... ;-)

Comment: Thanks, i think the problem was I didn't understand the concept of how sockets worked. I thought I could just open a socket, and read data from the server as if it's like a database. Also may you check updated answer, My solution is correct right/makes sense?

Comment: You made my day by posting that picture. Thanks.

Comment: You helped me a lot too! I was stuck on this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: that null thing is going to leave me sleepless. where the heck did it come from?